# Question on how to create WCF silverlight 3 endpoints

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, wcf, silverlight

I wanted to consume a WCF service with a silverlight application and a asp.net mvc application, and I'm having difficulties to configure the service to support both requests.

these are my endpoints for the WCF config file.

```
  <service behaviorConfiguration="behaviorAction" name="Uniarchitecture.ProdutoService.ServiceImplementations.ProdutoService">
    <endpoint binding="wsHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="bindingAction" contract="Uniarchitecture.ProdutoService.ServiceContracts.IProdutoService">
      <identity>
        <dns value="localhost"/>
      </identity>
    </endpoint>
    <endpoint address="" binding="basicHttpBinding" contract="Uniarchitecture.ProdutoService.ServiceContracts.IProdutoService"/>

    <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
  </service>
```

I'm getting the following error:
A binding instance has already been associated to listen URI 'net.tcp://localhost:10377/ProdutoService'. If two endpoints want to share the same ListenUri, they must also share the same binding object instance. The two conflicting endpoints were either specified in AddServiceEndpoint() calls, in a config file, or a combination of AddServiceEndpoint() and config.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is trying to use two endpoints with *two bindings*... You can use multiple endpoints on the same service here, but they need to use the same binding.

And since Silverlight **only supports BasicHttpBinding** you're kind of stuck with it.

```
<service behaviorConfiguration="behaviorAction" name="Uniarchitecture.ProdutoService.ServiceImplementations.ProdutoService">
    <endpoint binding="**basic**HttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="bindingAction" contract="Uniarchitecture.ProdutoService.ServiceContracts.IProdutoService"/>
    <endpoint address="" binding="basicHttpBinding" contract="Uniarchitecture.ProdutoService.ServiceContracts.IProdutoService"/>
</service>
```

Comment: Just a note, Silverlight 3 supports a binary binding in addition to BasicHttpBinding. In fact, its the new default when you create a new Silverlight-enabled WCF service.

Comment: I just need then to use 1 endpoint for both? Or should I use the binary binding for both?

Comment: I've made only one endpoit for basichttpbinding now I'm getting this error :
Contract requires Session, but Binding 'BasicHttpBinding' doesn't support it or isn't configured properly to support it.

Answer (score 0):

In your config, the addresses of the two endpoints are the same. With HTTP bindings, you can have multiple endpoints for a service, but you need to specify different addresses for them. Change the *address* of the basicHttpBinding endpoint to fix this problem.